# Allow users to create files but not edit and delete them

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

Is it possible to allow users creating new files inside a folder but not modifying them?

I'm trying to set such permissions but the problem is that when I disable `write attributes` and `write extended attributes`, users can't create files.

[image]

Users can't create files inside this folder, but, they can modify them. I want opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Advanced Security Settings window, disable inheritance clearing all the entries, and add these:

- Allow Administrators "Full control" on "This folder, subfolders, and files"
- Allow SYSTEM "Full control" on "This folder, subfolders, and files"
- Allow Authenticated Users the basic permissions "Read & execute", "List folder contents", "Read", and "Write" to "This folder only"
- Allow CREATOR OWNER "Full control" to "Subfolders and files only"
- Allow Authenticated Users the basic permissions "Read & execute", "List folder contents", and "Read" to "This folder, subfolders, and files"

The magic happens in the fourth bullet, where we add permissions for CREATOR OWNER. When inherited by new files, that entry will be changed into one that applies to the creator. You can skip the final bullet if you don't want everyone to be able to read all the files.

[image: advanced security settings]

To verify that the ACLs were entered correctly, here's the output of `icacls` on the folder:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(RX,W)
CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

Comment: Won't this allow the user who creates a file to modify it later?

Comment: @bendodge Yes; if that's not the desired behavior, you can remove the entry for `CREATOR OWNER`.

Answer (score 1):

I removed 'Delete' permission from the selected user group for the "folder and all sub-folders and files", and that gave me exactly what you asked for.

Since a modify operation is actually a copy-delete-reWrite operation, removing the delete removes both the ability to Delete files and Modify files.

I hope this easy answer will help someone.

Comment: Removing the Delete permission does not prevent a file from being modified, this isn't correct. As stated in [this](https://superuser.com/a/745950/491495) reply for a similar/duplicate question, modifying a file doesn't imply deletion.  In order to modify the file, the Write Attributes permission is needed to obtain a lock on the file to prevent concurrent modifications. With "Write" permissions on the directory users will still be able to modify the contents, as Write confers the Write Attributes permission.  Instead the folder should have Create files / write data permission only.