# Samba share permissions: Allow creating files, but not editing/deleting

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I want to create a Samba share (with my NAS running on Linux) where Users are allowed to:

- Create new files and new folders

And or are not allowed to:

- Delete or edit files or folders

Since Linux only has rwx-Permissions without distinguishing between "write" and "rewrite" I wonder, whether this is possible.

(Although the OS and context is different, I want something similar to [Allow users to create files but not edit and delete them](https://superuser.com/q/1145359/831268). Additionally, folders added by the user should follow the same rules: no changing/deleting of files/folders in them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of a semi-answers [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933466&p=11729534#post11729534) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/samba-share-with-read-write-but-no-delete-to-users-4175463175/#post4958615), and I think it's as close as you're going to get.

Basically, you need to set the owner of the files to not be a Samba user and the group of the files to one that the Samba user is not a member of (you can create a dummy group if needs be).

```
chown -R root:emptygroup * /path/to/dir/
```

Then set the sticky bit on the files to 1:

```
chmod -R 1777 /path/to/dir/
```

> **RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT**
>
> The  restricted  deletion  flag  or  sticky  bit is a single bit,
>   whose interpretation depends on the file type.  **For directories, it 
>   prevents unprivileged  users  from  removing or renaming a file in the
>   directory unless they  own  the  file  or  the  directory;**  this  is 
>   called  the restricted  deletion  flag  for the directory, and is
>   commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp.

The linked posts talk about the need to schedule a cron job that sets the permissions on newly created files, but in your smb.conf file you could put the following lines that should take care of this situation:

```
inherit owner=yes
inherit permissions=yes
```