# NTFS Folder Permissions

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions, shared-folders, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am trying to set folder & file "Restricted_Users" group permission on `Shared-Folder` as below:

```
\\Shared-Folder\Sub-Folder(s)\Sub-folder...(n)\File(s)
```

- Can Access/View folder(s) `Shared-Folder`, `Sub-Folder(s)` and `Sub-folder ....(n)`
- Can't Add/Update/Delete folder(s) `Shared-Folder`, `Sub-Folder(s)` and `Sub-folder ....(n)`
- Full Control (View/Add/Update/Delete) on file(s) contained in folder(s) `Sub-Folder(s)` and `Sub-folder ....(n)`

I have created permission as below but the file can't be updated in the shared folder by the restricted user group.

What am I doing wrong with permission? Hope for your kindly suggestion.

**Current Permission**
[image: Current Permission]

**Access is denied while file update**
[image: Access is denied while file update]

With References:

1. [Teachnet Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx)
2. [NTFS Permissions - Create Files and Folder but prevent Deletion and Modification](https://superuser.com/questions/745923/ntfs-permissions-create-files-and-folder-but-prevent-deletion-and-modification)

Comment: As you can see by the permissions you set "append data" is not permitted. Straight up overwriting the file should be.

Comment: @Seth if i set "append data" permission, user can add folder too.

Comment: Yes, because you apply it to this folder, subfolders and files. If you select folders and files it should only count for items within that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chatting reference with @ramhound and @Seth i got solutions for my query.

After splitting permission `This folder subfolders and file` into `This folder and subfolders` and `Files only`.

I set following permission for  `This folder and subfolders`

- Traverse folder / execute file
- List folder / read data
- Read attributes
- Read extended attributes
- Create file and write data
- Write attributes
- Write extended attributes
- Read permission

[image: Folder & File]

and `Full control` for `Files only`

[image: Files only]

and make disabled `inheritance`