# Folder Permissions (Save into Read-Only)

Tags: permissions, filesystems, file-permissions, file-sharing

I have a folder containing files that I would like to be read-only.  However, I would also like users to be able to save files into that read-only folder.

What permissions do I need to check for each user?  This is for windows 10

Comment: Sounds like you need a subfolder within a main folder that's for them to read only with NTFS permissions set on that subfolder explicitly with inheritance disabled. Then you allow others modify access to the main folder.I suppose. Otherwise you set the permissions explicitly on the files within the main folder with inheritance disabled which you want them to only have read-only access to and allow modify to the others on the main folder. Quick thoughts without testing if you want it enforced with NTFS rather than file "read-only" attribute which can be easily circumvented I think.

Comment: When a user saves a file to a folder, the inherited permission of the file that is created will be based on the user's permission to that folder.  So while you can make existing files read-only, using the obvious file attribute, any new files would not inherit that permission due to the required permissions on the folder in order allow users to create new files in that directory.  If you tell us the problem you are trying to solve, the answer to your problem, might answer the question you have asked.

Comment: What OS does the question refer to?

Comment: The specific problem that I had was that I changed permissions to prevent people from editing.  Ideally, I want them to be able to make changes to a file from a different location and save it in the read only folder as a 'revision' so that there is a read only revision history type of folder.  However, when going to save into that folder, it came up as permission denied

Comment: Brett - Are you running WIndows, Linux, Mac, or what OS (Operating System) wise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NTFS Permissions - Create Files and Folder but prevent Deletion and Modification](https://superuser.com/questions/745923/ntfs-permissions-create-files-and-folder-but-prevent-deletion-and-modification)