# NTFS Permissions to Save directly to folder

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, network-shares

I'm trying to setup the NTFS permissions on a shared folder to allow certain users the ability to read files and create files within the folder but not be able to modify or delete them. I've followed what's on [NTFS Permissions - Create Files and Folder but prevent Deletion and Modification](https://superuser.com/questions/745923/ntfs-permissions-create-files-and-folder-but-prevent-deletion-and-modification) and am able to accomplish most of the task.

The issue I'm having though is users are not able to save directly to the folder from a text editor or other programs; they have to drag and drop their files/folders from an unprotected location, which is a little much to explain to the current user base.

Also, is there a way to be able to create folders directly within the share and rename it at creation? As of now, when users "Create Folder" and attempt to rename before saving it, it generates an error and I'm left with a bunch of "New Folder" folders in the share. This problem, I'm assuming, is probably related to the same issue as the previous question.

I've tried enabling write attributes but that ends up allowing users to edit the files.

Server is running Windows Server 2016

Answer (score -1):

rename = delete/(re)create on NTFS does it not?

If you add CREATE OWNER permission from Advanced Security Setting on the folder where the user would create a sub-folder  and change the applies to drop down to "This Folder and Sub-folders" and tick the Modify box in addition to the default attrib's does this give the desired effect? Not sure if this would allow users to delete and/or modify files that they create also - but I don't think so.

Comment: I tried adding the Creator Owner group with Modify permissions and yes, it ends up allowing the creator to create, edit, and delete their files and folders, so not what I wanted to accomplish. Thanks for the suggestion though.